# How to secure a web-service location?

Tags: java, web-services, security, authentication, jax-ws

I have a web service which is secured with an SSL EV certificate. Lets say it´s located at:
`https://webservice.justawebservice.com/webservice/`. Users are able to send messages to this web-service.

When a malicious person obtains possession of this URL, said person can show the WSDL and web the service location. But most importantly, he will be able to send in messages. There is some kind of authentication on the web-service, but only happens when a message is sent in (the message contains an username and password). A malicious person will be able to flood said webservice with loads of messages, which may cause it to go offline.

I want to secure this area, so when said person goes to the link he is asked for some kind of authentication.

What is the best way to do this? (If it's possible)

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your objective is to prevent DOS type of attack 'flooding with requests' then authentication is not a proper way of doing it as even properly authenticated client could cause flood by nature of not understanding how to use API or by bugs in his code etc.

Proper way IMHO would be to develop some sort of 'circuit breaker' pattern in your code (as WS interceptor perhaps) which would look at number of requests coming (either from particular user or from ip address or in total or all of the above) and shortcut call execution by returning the error to the caller, therefore not consuming much of the resources on your system.

This would be a good first step but not a complete guarantee against DOS attack (as your service would still consume resources to accept request and interpret it). Next step would be to try to block such clients on lowest level possible - e.g. on firewall just dropping TCP packets - there are few firewalls packages that simplify this task - e.g. AFP with ddos deflate and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I will discuss these ideas.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to protect the URL of this webservice with an username and password? When a malicious person aquires this URL, he will be asked for authentication.

Comment: If you want you can get access to HTTP headers in your WS method and get username/password from there, mimicking simple HTTP authentication mechanism: webServiceContex.getMessageContext().get("Username") etc. returning HTTP 401 (Not Authorized) on authentication failure. Better yet do it in WS interceptor

Answer (score 1):

A soley person/user won't be the problem, but could create a bot, that flood your service.

Options:

- On the firewall level, keep flooding packages [away](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-10-how-to-block-common-attack.html).
- Use client-authentification with a [client certificate](http://www.maximporges.com/2009/11/18/configuring-tomcat-ssl-clientserver-authentication/). Most bots abandon when client certification is required.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Reading those links now, I've heard the term client certificate earlier in my work environment (I'm an intern). The tutorial seems promising. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to protect the URL of this webservice with an username and password? When a malicious person aquires this URL, he will be asked for authentication.